# How to get value of textinput with Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and as i'm not able to practice on PySide (some dynamic libraries broken or i don't know what) i want to try this huge tool.

I'm lost right now, i tried to do like this :
[Get textinput value in Kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314466/get-textinput-value-in-kivy-app)

But i don't do this in the same way :

```
<ProduitScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 2
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: 'Nom du produit'
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: nom
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: 'Prix'
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: prix
        Button:
            text: 'Ajouter'
            on_press: self.ajouter()
        Button:
            text: 'Quitter'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

So, the Button with the field text filled with 'Ajouter' has to permit me to get the value of both fields and add them into a list but :

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'ajouter'
```

And in my class it's defined like that :

```
class ProduitScreen(Screen):
    def ajouter():
        print "%s au prix de %d a ete ajoute" % (self.nom.txt , float(self.prix.txt))
```

Does someone can tell me how to do that ?

EDIT : The blackquote doesn't save the indentation so there is the full code http://pastebin.com/W1WJ8NcL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ajouter` method is a member of `ProduitScreen` not `Button` so you should use `root` to refer to it:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Ajouter'
        on_press: root.ajouter()
```

Also fix issues on your definition of `ajouter`:

```
class ProduitScreen(Screen):
    def ajouter(self):
        print "%s au prix de %f a ete ajoute" % (self.nom.text , float(self.prix.text))
```

In order to use `nom` and `prix` inside your python code, add this to kv code:

```
<ProduitScreen>:
    nom: nom
    prix: prix
```

Comment: It definitely works ! 
What function can i call with on_press to quit the application ? (universal function for android, unix, windows etc ...)

Comment: try `from kivy.app import App;
App.get_running_app().stop()`

Comment: Awesome. I'll have a few words with you if i've some trouble using Kivy. Thank you a lot dude.

Comment: A Nth problem. Now i know how to fetch datas from GUI, how to use datas into GUI ? I've a list and i want to generate Buttons and Labels from it. How to ? ^^.

Comment: Elaborate, if you feel the explanation is big, I suggest to ask it as new question and I will be happy yo answer and so many other users.

Comment: Ok i'll do. See you on.