# Variable not updated with TextInput content after content change in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I have created an edit window in Kivy allowing to display content from a dictionary and to change the content of the related items (text).
First all the TextInput fields are initialised with the data from the first process step stored in a dictionary. There is a button for triggering and displaying the next step. But the user might change the contents of a specific TextInput field in the meantime. When changed, the new TextInput content shall be assigned to a local variable (in the example below represented in a print). In short I have the following code. Unfortunately the variable is not updated. What's wrong?

The python part:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class pezHome(Widget):
    title = StringProperty()

    def init_pez(self):
        self.title = "Enter your title"

    def update(self):
        new_title = self.title
        print "New title is: ", new_title

class pezApp(App):
    def build(self):
        homeWin = pezHome()
        homeWin.init_editor()
        return homeWin

pezApp().run()
```

The related kv file:

```
<pezHome>:
    TextInput:
            text: root.title
            on_text: root.title
            readonly: False
```

Comment: Luckily I have found a solution in another item: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32090870/5708480

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your *update* method... here is the needed change

```
<pezHome>:
    TextInput:
        text: root.title
        on_text: root.update() # was root.title ...
        readonly: False
```

Comment: Dear Yoav, I am sorry but I was not very clear in my example. I have updated the code parts as I had an init cycle in my code. The problem is that in the form pezHome there is a field called title. Initially this field contains the text "Enter your title". (The form consists of several fields....). Now the user may change the contents of the fields. Once done clicks on the save button (which calls the update function) but the new contents of these fields are not available in this context. Print still prints "Enter your title". So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Aaaaaand here I am with the same exact problem, Bill. Did you find an answer?